# Lizmap add point to PostGIS layer - correct layer settings?

Tags: qgis-plugins, web-service, lizmap

Not able to add point to the layer using lizmap.
I'w been following this guidance
https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-documentation/blob/master/source/publish/advanced_lizmap_config.rst#id28

Point is not saved & lizmap page says:
"An error has been raised when saving the form!"

Lizmap error log says:
.... 2018-04-24 12:51:46    **[2]   openlog() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given** ....

Lizmap messages log says:
2018-04-24 12:51:40 ::1 **default   SQL =  INSERT INTO "public"."mytablename" ("geom", "Name", "description" ) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(21.785181524973595 63.10872517176041)', 4326), 'blaablaa', 'blaaa' )  RETURNING "id";**

My setup is Win10
Lizmap 3.2Beta + QGIS Server 2.18.18 + Postgres 10.2 & PostGis
plugin Lizmap 2.4.0

Layer "id" field i set to hidden using QGIS layer properties. + tick on WMS & WFS. And "id" type is integer and type name int4

By using PGAdmin i'm able to see that this id field has a Default value defined as nextval('mytablename_id_seq'::regclass). this field is a primary key.

On Lizmap plugin this layer is added to be edited with all the options +
Popup enbabled + qgis setting

Answer (score 1):

Seems that my layer was 3D (PointZ) type. 
And from pgAdmin i had to execute:

**ALTER TABLE mytablename
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point)
USING ST_Force2D(geom);**

Comment: You can also accept your own answer: it is not frowned upon here, but welcomed.